# Создание уровней в Unity 3D

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Изучаю Unity и возник вопрос как облегчить создание 3D уровней, потому что перетаскивать объекты просто так неудобно. Возможно есть специальные инструметы?
Пожалуйста помогите.

На фото приблизительный набросок уровня.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы упростить себе жизнь и не перетаскивать всё вручную, можно хранить конфигурацию уровня(напр. двумерный массив с ID 3д-тайлов) в текстовом файле или в [Scriptable Object](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html), а затем через скрипт спавнить соответствующие элементы уровня.

Если пойти дальше, в Unity можно использовать Custom editor и Custom window.

[Custom editor](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html) - позволяет кастомизировать отрисовку MonoBehaviour в окне инспектора: добавить кнопочек, дополнительного ввода и вывода информации.

[Custom window](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-EditorWindows.html) - можно создать кастомное окно для редактирования уровня, например вынести туда ввод размера уровня и кнопку "сгенерировать".